# Kotlin data class copy with changed var value

Tags: kotlin

Why can't you copy data class object with var value change?

```
data class AppState(var list: List<Image> = ArrayList<Image>(),
                val uiState: UIState = UIState.LIST,
                val isFetching: Boolean = false)

...

val list = state!!.list.sublist(0,1);
state.copy(list = list)        // No change
state.copy(isFetching = true)  // Works like a charm
```

Comment: You know that `copy` returns a new instance, and does not modify the receiver?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `copy` method does not mutate the original object. It returns a new object with the changed values. I tried your example, and both of your copies work as expected when I capture the returned object in a new `val`:

```
val list = state!!.list.subList(0,1)

// Creates a new object with the new list.
val withNewList = state.copy(list = list)

// Creates a new object with the new isFetching.
val withNewIsFetching = withNewList.copy(isFetching = true)
```

If you want to mutate the list-value of your `state`-object, you can just do this:

```
val list = state!!.list.subList(0,1)
state.list = list
```

Comment: Also, you should do `val list = state?.list?.subList(0,1) ?: emptyList()`, instead of using the `!!`-operator to avoid NullPointerExceptions.